# SAML2 SSO Integration

Tags: saml-2.0

I have an existing J2EE application which provides some specific features after logging in to the application. 
I have to provide SSO to just ONE of the customer who logs into our application while the rest of the customers would still use the login page and login with their credentials.
I am planning to use OpenAM Fedlet act as SP deployed as a separate application in our container.
I need some help in understanding if i need a full blown OpenAM instance deployed within us. Please provide any insights if you may have on this .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fedlet as an SP for this user. The trick is identifying this particular user and initiating SSO for this person, and going to the login screen for everyone else.

Comment: Identifying wouldn't be a problem as this SSO customer will not use the login page but instead send a SAML request as IDP to the fedlet which will validate its arributes and then forward the request to my application to establish a session programtically. The other users would just use the application login page to access the application.
My understanding is the customer would be the IDP and the fedlet would act as SP and redirect the request to my application for session creation and take them to home page. Is that valid ?